# than the number of real stars visible in the sky (comparative)

Tags: anglais, comparatifs

In the French language, I'm searching for a natural way to say,

- In a planetarium you can see a lot more stars than real stars visible in the sky.

I'm having difficulty in how I should use comparative, how I should connect a part before "than" with a part after it. Here's my try,

- Tu peux voir beaucoup plus des étoiles dans un planétarium que celles visibles dans le ciel.

Answer (score 4):

La comparaison portant ici sur les lieux plus que sur les étoiles, la construction la plus simple (et donc à privilégier) est :

plus de + *ici* que *là*

- *Tu peux voir beaucoup plus d'étoiles dans un planétarium que dans le ciel.*

La construction :

- *Tu peux voir beaucoup plus d'étoiles dans un planétarium que tu ne peux en voir dans le ciel*

serait, elle aussi, tout à fait correcte.
Tu fais alors porter la comparaison sur le fait de voir, mais comme *voir* n'est pas immédiatement antécédent, c'est alors toute la proposition principale que tu compares, ce qui t'impose une proposition subordonnée.
Ce qui, sur ce coup, peut sembler un peu... overkill. ;)

Answer (score -2):

- Tu peux voir beaucoup plus des étoiles dans un planétarium que celles
  visibles dans le ciel.

C'est correct !

Comment: Non, *beaucoup plus des étoiles* n'est pas correct.